# Jquery Keyup script to update input value not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a script that adds up data-attributes from checkboxes, I modified the script to be able to allow users to manually add their own entries into a `text input` that the keyup function copies into the `data-cost=""` and `debt=""` attributes, which a plugin recalculates the total into the blue div box on the right side in this [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/JgY2t/13/). This functionality works, as you can see in the fiddle

But I also want data that is copied into the data-attributes to also be copied into the `value=""`. The plugin uses the value to display it in the yellow summary box on the right, but every time I modify the keyup script, the calculation stops working and the value does not show up in the summary.

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mikeef74/JgY2t/13/)

This is the keyup script:

```
function calculateTotalFor(){
    $('#jquery-order-form').data('jprice').onChange();
}
$(function () {
    $(document).on('keyup blur paste', '.balance', function() {  //Changed here
        var $self = $(this),
        $checkbox = $self.closest('li').find('input:checkbox');
        setTimeout(function() {
            var str = $self.val();
            $checkbox.data('cost',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            $checkbox.data('debt',str.replace(/^\$/, ''));
            calculateTotalFor();
        }, 0)
    })    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `$checkbox.val(str.replace(/^\$/, ''));` before `calculateTotalFor();` and it seems to work.